# Is there a cap to the amount of dust you can have?

Tags: hearthstone

Are there any limits to the amount of arcane dust that you can have?

I am currently at 1990, and don't really have any crafting needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no meaningful cap on Arcane Dust.

You can stockpile as much as you need, and are not incentivized to "use it up".